# My Shopping Cart is not working as expected in ASP.NET MVC 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, session-cookies

My cart is working fine in localhost but when i have hosted in cloud hosting it is not working well problem is that when i click add to cart button it will add one product with one quantity but when i add another product in the cart again it will override the previous one and show only one product in cart when i have added on last.. i don't know whats wrong with the sessions it will override the session again i guess. And another problem is that my my update cart button's functionalities and delete button functionalities in cart is not working it throw exception

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

I have a controller name shoppingCartController here is the code

```
namespace Medi.Areas.User.Controllers
{
public class ShoppingCartController : Controller
{
ArrayList arr = new ArrayList();
int id;


BLL.IRepository<tbl_Product> de = new BLL.IRepository<tbl_Product>();
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}
private int isExisting(int id)
{
    List<Items> cart = (List<Items>)Session["cart"];
    for (int i = 0; i < cart.Count; i++)
        if (cart[i].Pr.ProductID == id)
            return i;
    return -1;


}
public ActionResult Delete(int id)
{
    int index = isExisting(id);
    List<Items> cart = (List<Items>)Session["cart"];
    cart.RemoveAt(index);
    Session["cart"] = cart;
    return PartialView("_pvCart");
}
public ActionResult OrderNow(string q)
{
    if (Session["cart"] == null)
    {
        List<Items> cart = new List<Items>();
        cart.Add(new Items(de.GetById(Convert.ToInt32(q)), 1));
        Session["cart"] = cart;
        // ViewBag.quantity = new MultiSelectList(cart,"Quantity","Quantity");
        //  cart[1]

    }
    else
    {
        id = Convert.ToInt32(q);
        List<Items> cart = (List<Items>)Session["cart"];
        int index = isExisting(id);
        if (index == -1)
            cart.Add(new Items(de.GetById(id), 1));
        else
            cart[index].Quantity++;
        Session["cart"] = cart;
        // ViewBag.quantity = new MultiSelectList(cart, "Quantity", "Quantity");
    }

    return View("Cart");
}
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult UpdateCart(int[] ProductID,int [] quantity )
{
    int[] x = new int[4];
    int[] y = new int[4];
    List<Items> cart = (List<Items>)Session["cart"];
    for (int i = 0; i < cart.Count; i++)
    {
        x[i] = ProductID[i];
        y[i] = quantity[i];
        updcart(x[i],y[i]);
    }

    Session["cart"] = cart;
    return PartialView("_pvCart");

}

public void updcart(int id,int quantity) {
    List<Items> cart = (List<Items>)Session["cart"];
    int index = isExisting(id);
    if (index == -1)
        cart.Add(new Items(de.GetById(id), 1));
    else
        cart[index].Quantity = quantity;
    Session["cart"] = cart;
}
    }
   }
```

and here is the view name Cart.cshtml

```
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Cart";
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js"></script>

 @using (Ajax.BeginForm("UpdateCart", "ShoppingCart", new AjaxOptions() {  HttpMethod = "POST", UpdateTargetId = "MyData", InsertionMode =  InsertionMode.Replace }))
{
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
<br />
<br />
<div id="MyData">
   @{Html.RenderPartial("_pvCart");}
```

and here is the partial view code

```
@using Medi.Models;

<script src="~/Scripts/metro.min.js"></script>
<table class="table hovered" cellpadding=" 2" cellspacing="2" border="1px">
<tr class="info">
<th></th>

<th>Name</th>
<th>Price</th>
<th>Quantity</th>
<th>Sub Total</th>
</tr>
@{
decimal s = 0;
}
@foreach (Items item in (List<Items>)Session["cart"])
{
<input id="ProductID" name="ProductID" type="hidden" value="@item.Pr.ProductID" />
s = s + (Convert.ToInt32(item.Pr.Price) * item.Quantity);
<tr>

    <th>@Ajax.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.Pr.ProductID }, new AjaxOptions() { HttpMethod = "POST", UpdateTargetId = "MyData", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace }, new { @class = "mif-cross" })</th>

    <td>@item.Pr.ProductName</td>
    <td>@item.Pr.Price</td>
    <td>
        <input name="quantity" id="quantity" type="text" style="width:25px;" value="@item.Quantity" />



    </td>
    <td>@(item.Pr.Price * item.Quantity)</td>
</tr>
}
</table><br />
<hr />
<table cellpadding="1px" cellspacing="1px" style="float:right;">
<tr align="center" colspan="5" style="background-color:gray;">
<td><h3 style="padding:1px;">Total</h3></td>
<td> <h3 style="padding:1px;">Rs @s</h3></td>

</tr>
</table>
```

here is the model class

```
using BOL;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

 namespace Medi.Models
  {
   public class Items

 {

  tbl_Product pr = new tbl_Product();

public tbl_Product Pr
{
    get { return pr; }
    set { pr = value; }
}
int quantity;

public int Quantity { get; set; }
public Items()
{

}
public Items(tbl_Product product, int quantity)
{
    this.Pr = product;
    this.Quantity = quantity;
}

 }
  }
```

i have also write this code in web.config

```
<httpCookies httpOnlyCookies="true" requireSSL="true"/>
<sessionState mode="InProc"/>
```

Comment: Just about the only thing worse that keeping the user's cart in a session is using an in-proc session to do it. It's such a lovely thing when the app pool restarts and all the users carts get blown away. Companies *really* love that.

Comment: @Chris pratt Please give me some solution..?

Comment: How about session AND database? When you read shopping cart data, check your session first. If it's there, you save a trip to the database (if your session isn't backed by a database). When you write, write to session and persist to the database. That way, you get speedy reads and the user doesn't lose their cart when they close their browser

Comment: @Jelle its working when i remove this `<httpCookies httpOnlyCookies="true" requireSSL="true"/>` whats the reason behind,my cart is sucure or not if i remove `<httpCookies httpOnlyCookies="true" requireSSL="true"/>` this line of code